# Encrypted layer 2 tunnel over Internet for a contiguous subnet

Tags: vpn, sonicwall, l2tp

I have two offices that are connected at layer 2 with fiber on a primary link with contiguous subnets on each end(it won't change anytime soon). It works just fine, I have full end-to-end layer 2 connectivity.

I want to setup a secondary link, over the internet as a backup in case the primary link fails.

I have SonicWalls on both gateways and I'd like to establish another layer2 tunnel in case the primary link fails. My preference is not to include any additional device/server, otherwise I'll have to use L2TP tunnel on two additional devices behind the firewalls on each end.

Has anybody built such a tunnel with sonicwalls?